# 5 speed to 6 speed transmission swap reprogramming?

Tags: transmission, pontiac, electronic-control-module, vibe

I have a 2003 Pontiac Vibe (which is the same as Toyota Matrix) that the transmission locked up. For what I researched it is a very common problem with the Vibe. Solution suggested was to swap it for a 6 speed that fits perfectly without any modification. My question is...would I have to reprogram the computer after the swap being a different gear transmission?
Thnaks in advance!

Comment: Can't answer extensively, but yes, you would need to swap or splice in the wiring harness from the manual transmission equipped car.

Comment: from what ive read and heard only thing you need to change is the cv shafts due to the 6 speed has shorter cv shafts than the 5speed im dealing with the same thing but i believe being its a standard you wouldnt have to but if its auto then yes